# How to check/uncheck checkbox based on localStorage state

Tags: javascript, html, templates, input, checkbox

I'm trying to persist checkbox state in a HTML (Flask/Jinja2) template using just html and CSS, but I've running into strange behavior where even though localStorage saves the state correctly, state is always set as true on load. I've looked up a ton of answers and have been stuck for a couple hours and I don't understand it isn't working:

HTML:

```
<input id="returnHeatmapsHtmlCheckbox" 
type="checkbox" name="returnHeatmapsHtml" onclick="saveCheckboxState(this)" />
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = onPageLoad();
      function onPageLoad (){
document.getElementById("returnHeatmapsHtmlCheckbox").checked = localStorage.getItem("returnHeatmapsHtmlCheckbox");
}
// <!-- Persist checkboxes  -->
      function saveCheckboxState(e){
        var id = e.id
        var val = e.checked
        console.log("Saved value ID: " + id + ","+ val)
        localStorage.setItem(id,val)
        console.log("Loaded value ID: " + localStorage.getItem(id,val))
        console.log(getSavedCheckboxState("returnHeatmapsHtmlCheckbox"))
      }
      function getSavedCheckboxState(v){
        const default_dict = {
          "returnHeatmapsHtmlCheckbox": false
        };

        if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
          return default_dict[v];// return false by default. 
        };
        return localStorage.getItem(v);
      }
  </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you !

Comment: localStorage will convert the saved value to a string, so it could be that you need to convert it back to a boolean when you get it from localStorage. Try `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(v)`

Comment: Thanks! It turned out to be this, I solved it using an if statement:
```if (getSavedCheckboxState("returnHeatmapsHtmlCheckbox")=='true'){
document.getElementById("returnHeatmapsHtmlCheckbox").checked = true
}else{
document.getElementById("returnHeatmapsHtmlCheckbox").checked = false
}

Your way seems better

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and took the liberty to refactor some excerpts, I tried to keep it as similar as possible to what you did, you can see the result below.

HTML:

```html
<input id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />
```

JS:

```js
// get the checkbox element
const myCheckbox = document.querySelector('#myCheckbox')

// responsible for setting a value in localStorage
// following the "checked" state
const setStorageState = (e) => {
  const { id, checked } = e.target
  localStorage.setItem(id, checked)
}

// responsible for searching and converting to Boolean
// the value set in localStorage
const getStorageState = (storageName) => {
  return localStorage.getItem(storageName) === 'true'
}

// responsible for changing the state of your checkbox
const setCheckboxStateOnLoad = () => {
  myCheckbox.checked = getStorageState('myCheckbox')
}

// calls the function "setStorageState" every time
// the user clicks on his checkbox
myCheckbox.addEventListener('click', setStorageState)

// calls the "setCheckboxStateOnLoad" function
// after the DOM content is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setCheckboxStateOnLoad)
```

Hope it helps and sorry for the bad english :)